# How do I imitate a sass for loop in a property?

Tags: loops, sass

I have some very repetitive css that I would like for sass to simplify. Essentially I have a series of items that have a number background stripes based on their level. I am using background gradients to create these stripes. I tried to use a for loop inside of my background-image property, but apparently that is not acceptable sass. This is a very simplistic example of what I am attempting to do.

Any ideas for how I can get around this for loop limitation?

```
.master {
    @for $i from 1 through 10 {

    .item-#{$i} {
        background-image:
            @for $j from 1 through $1 {
                linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
            }
            linear-gradient(#fff 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255,.0) 1px);
            }
    }
}
```

Desired result:

```
.master .item-1 {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(#fff 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255,.0) 1px);
}

.master .item-2 {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(#fff 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255,.0) 1px);
}

.master .item-3 {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(#fff 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255,.0) 1px);
}

etc...

.master .item-10 {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px),
        linear-gradient(#fff 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255,.0) 1px);
}
```

Comment: What is the desired *output*?

Comment: You don't. Instead you create a variable, manipulate the variable with a for-loop, and then apply it to the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this approach

```
.master {
  @for $i from 1 through 10 {

    $lg : "";
    @for $j from 1 through $i {
      $lg : $lg + "linear-gradient(90deg, red 7px, #fff 1px), ";
    }

    .item-#{$i} {
      background-image: #{$lg}linear-gradient(#fff 1px, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 1px);
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it on [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/)